# Is there a faster way to take screenshots on macOS for a Python piano tiles bot?

Tags: python, macos, automation

I made a piano tiles bot with python, but there is a problem: it takes too much time to take a screenshot (0.5 seconds). It should take less than 0.1 seconds for it to work. I'm on macOS, so  I think screenshots are a lot slower than windows.

The code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
from pynput.mouse import Controller as MouseController, Button
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

mouse = MouseController()

pixel_coords = [(590, 490), (492, 490), (678, 490), (766, 490)]
running = True

def click(x, y):
    mouse.position = (x, y)
    mouse.click(Button.left)

def play():
    global running
    while running:
        print("Hey")
        x = time.time()
        screen = ImageGrab.grab()
        for coord in pixel_coords:
            value = screen.getpixel((coord[0], coord[1]))
            if value in [(0, 0, 0, 255), (15, 20, 19, 255), (13, 32, 41, 255), (0, 161, 201, 255)]:
                click(coord[0], coord[1])
        print(f"Time taken: {round(time.time() - x, 4)}")

def on_press(key):
    global running
    if key == KeyCode(char="q"):
        running = False
        print("Stopped")
        quit()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    play()
    listener.join()
```

I tried different modules such as pyautogui and PIL, but they are very slow.

Comment: What does “piano tiles” mean in this context?

Comment: The video game.

Comment: Is it taking the screenshot that takes a long time, or running the loop that appears to simulate a click on every pixel in the resulting image?  (your code appears to measure the time it takes for both actions)

Comment: The screen shot takes a long time: 0.5 - 1 seconds to take it, and 0.005 to click